# jQuery - Expand / Collapse with grid / list view states

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simulate a `grid / list` view with a `collapsable menu` that **only applies when in list view** however my expand / collapse code currently effects both states (list view and grid view).

I want to only allow expand / collapse when in `list view`, else if in grid view - show all. I still need the `#toggleAll` button to work with the list view items however I do not know how to rearange my code to only apply if `$(.funded__list).hasClass("list")`.

```js
$("#view_list").on("click", function() {
  $("#list_log").attr("class", "funded__list list");
  $("#view_grid").removeClass("view__toggle--active");
  $("#view_list").addClass("view__toggle--active");
});

$("#view_grid").on("click", function() {
  $("#list_log").attr("class", "funded__list grid");
  $("#view_list").removeClass("view__toggle--active");
  $("#view_grid").addClass("view__toggle--active");
});

if ($(".funded__list").hasClass("list")) {
  $(".btn--media").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".funded__item").find(".funded__right").toggle();

    //If everything is visible
    if ($(".funded__right:visible").length == $(".funded__right").length) {
      $("#toggleAll").text("Collapse");
    }
    //Else if everything is invisible
    else if ($(".funded__right:hidden").length == $(".funded__right").length) {
      $("#toggleAll").text("Expand");
    }
  });
}
$("#toggleAll").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Collapse") {
    $(".funded__right").hide();
    $(this).text("Expand");
  } else {
    $(".funded__right").show();
    $(this).text("Collapse");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.view {
  display: flex;
}

.view>div {
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.view__toggle--active {
  background: blue;
}

.funded__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list .funded__item {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.list img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.funded__item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.list .funded__right {
  display: none;
}

.grid .funded__right {
  display: flex;
}

.grid button {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">
  <div id="view_grid" class="view__toggle">
    <div class="icon icon--grid">grid</div>
  </div>
  <div id="view_list" class="view__toggle view__toggle--active">
    <div class="icon icon--list">list</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="toggleAll" class="btn btn-primary expand-all">Expand</button>

<div id="list_log" class="funded__list list">
  <div class="funded__item">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/640x480" target="_blank">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </a>
    <div class="funded__right">
      <h3 class="name">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      Sample Text
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--media">Expand</button>
  </div>
  <div class="funded__item">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/640x480" target="_blank">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </a>
    <div class="funded__right">
      <h3 class="name">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      Sample Text
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--media">Expand</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the div `list_log` has class `list` depending on this you can restrict your toggle button to work on `grid` view .Also , on click of `list` view i have added condition if the button is expand hide or show the `funded__right` div because the grid view will show all div `list_log` so this will stop button to show or hide these divs if user has not selected `expand` in list view .Sorry if i missunderstood something .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#view_list").on("click", function() {
  $("#list_log").attr("class", "funded__list list");
  $("#view_grid").removeClass("view__toggle--active");
  $("#view_list").addClass("view__toggle--active");
  $("#toggleAll").text() == "Expand" ? $(".funded__right").hide() : $(".funded__right").show(); //check for toggletext..show or hide

});

$("#view_grid").on("click", function() {
  $("#list_log").attr("class", "funded__list grid");
  $("#view_list").removeClass("view__toggle--active");
  $("#view_grid").addClass("view__toggle--active");
  $(".funded__right").show(); //if grid slected show all by default


});

$(".btn--media").click(function() {
  //check div
  if ($("#list_log").hasClass("list")) {
    $(this).closest(".funded__item").find(".funded__right").toggle();

    //If everything is visible
    if ($(".funded__right:visible").length == $(".funded__right").length) {
      $("#toggleAll").text("Collapse");
    }
    //Else if everything is invisible
    else if ($(".funded__right:hidden").length == $(".funded__right").length) {
      $("#toggleAll").text("Expand");
    }
  }
});


$("#toggleAll").click(function() {
  //checking if the list_log div has class list
  if ($("#list_log").hasClass("list")) {
    if ($(this).text() == "Collapse") {
      $(".funded__right").hide();
      $(this).text("Expand");
    } else {
      $(".funded__right").show();
      $(this).text("Collapse");
    }

  } else {
    //grid so show all 
    $(".funded__right").show();


  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.view {
  display: flex;
}

.view>div {
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.view__toggle--active {
  background: blue;
}

.funded__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list .funded__item {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.list img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.funded__item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.list .funded__right {
  display: none;
}

.grid .funded__right {
  display: flex;
}

.grid button {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">
  <div id="view_grid" class="view__toggle">
    <div class="icon icon--grid">grid</div>
  </div>
  <div id="view_list" class="view__toggle view__toggle--active">
    <div class="icon icon--list">list</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="toggleAll" class="btn btn-primary expand-all">Expand</button>

<div id="list_log" class="funded__list list">
  <div class="funded__item">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/640x480" target="_blank">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </a>
    <div class="funded__right">
      <h3 class="name">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      Sample Text
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--media">Expand</button>
  </div>
  <div class="funded__item">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/640x480" target="_blank">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </a>
    <div class="funded__right">
      <h3 class="name">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      Sample Text
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--media">Expand</button>
  </div>
</div>
```